# How do I draw log_0.1 on tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

I am trying to draw y=log_(0.1) with tikz and I can't seem to find the correct syntax. Here's what I have at the moment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=0:$Y$] (y) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate (y1) at (0,-2);
\coordinate[label=90:$X$] (x) at (4,0);
\coordinate (x1) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate[label=-135:$O$] (o) at (0,0);

\draw[-latex] (x1)--(x);
\draw[-latex] (y1)--(y);
\draw plot[domain=0.3:3.8] (\x,{log10(\x)});
\draw plot[domain=2:3.8] (\x,{log0.1(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=0:$Y$] (y) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate (y1) at (0,-2);
\coordinate[label=90:$X$] (x) at (4,0);
\coordinate (x1) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate[label=-135:$O$] (o) at (0,0);

\draw[-latex] (x1)--(x);
\draw[-latex] (y1)--(y);
\draw plot[domain=0.3:3.8] (\x,{log10(\x)});
\draw plot[domain=0.3:3.8] (\x,{ log10(\x)/log10(0.1) });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basic base change of log. See here: http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log43/log43.html

Comment: Can you tell me what the \x command means?

Comment: @NIckBennett, not sure anymore!
I guess you could do something similar like this: `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}\addplot[blue,thick,domain=0.3:3.8]{log10(x)};\addplot[red,thick,domain=0.3:3.8]{log10(x)/log10(0.1};\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}`